# Using array of struct in a function?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a function that changes one value of the elements in an array of struct, but it isn't working, the function does nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Input:

```
300
9
1999
1050
301
5
2000
1200
20
```

Expected output:

```
300 1260
```

Actual output: nothing

```
  #include <stdio.h>

typedef struct 
{int codice;
int mese;
int anno;
int stipendio;}
dipendente;

void aumento (dipendente a[], int dim, int n){
int i;
for (i=0; i<dim; i++)
{if (a[i].anno<2000) a[i].stipendio=a[i].stipendio+(a[i].stipendio*n)/100;;
if (a[i].anno==2000)
    {if (a[i].mese<5)
    a[i].stipendio=a[i].stipendio+(a[i].stipendio*n)/100;}}
}

int main () {
int i;
int p;
dipendente a[2];
for (i=0; i<2; i++){
    scanf("%d",&a[i].codice);
    scanf("%d",&a[i].mese);
    scanf("%d",&a[i].anno);
    scanf("%d",&a[i].stipendio);
}
scanf("%d", &p);
aumento (a, 2, p);
for (i=0; i<2; i++)
 {if(a[i].stipendio>1200) 
    printf("%d %d", a[i].codice, a[i].stipendio);}
return 0; }
```

Comment: What input do you give to your program?

Comment: Please include the input, the expected output, and the actual output in the question. "It issn't working" is not a terribly useful bit of information.

Comment: You also should **enable all warnings in your compiler** and treat them as errors. There is at least one problem in the code which you could have avoided this way.

Comment: I have the warnings enabled, but the compiler doesn't show any

Comment: This code is very complicated for supposedly only changing one value in an array.

Comment: I believe @n.m. is referring to the integer division you are performing. `n/100` will yield `0` for all `0 <= n < 100`.

Comment: Get a better compiler then. The problem is `if (a[i].anno=2000)` .

Comment: @Sami no, the compiler won't warn about this mistake, it has no idea which division is right for you.

Comment: In addition please indent your code properly. My eyes bleed when I try to read it.

Comment: @n.m. I stand corrected :)

Comment: I changed both things, it's still not working

Comment: Here `a[i].stipendio*(n/100)` you did it wrong, the 2nd time you did it right. 1st multiply then devide.

Comment: A good time to start learning how to use a debugger was yesterday, but today is still not too late. Trace your prigram execution step by step and observe how variables change their values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There two problems.

1. As @n.m. pointed out in comments: `if (a[i].anno=2000)` is doing an assignment and is always true (because `2000` is true). You want to compare. Use double `==` for it `if (a[i].anno == 2000)`
2. As @SamiHult pointed out in comments: `n/100` will always be 0 for any `0 <= n && n < 100`, because `n` is an `int`. Use `double` or `float` to have floating point math. Or as @alk pointed out, you can first multiply then divide, so that you can stay in integer math `(a[i].stipendio * n) / 100`
3. This is good code, but indentation just hurts.

After fixing those errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int codice;
    int mese;
    int anno;
    int stipendio;
} dipendente;

void aumento(dipendente a[], int dim, int n) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        if (a[i].anno < 2000) {
            a[i].stipendio = a[i].stipendio + a[i].stipendio * ((double)n / 100);
        }
        if (a[i].anno == 2000) { 
            if (a[i].mese < 5) {
                a[i].stipendio = a[i].stipendio + a[i].stipendio * ((double)n / 100);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int i;
    int p;
    dipendente a[2];

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        scanf("%d", &a[i].codice);
        scanf("%d", &a[i].mese);
        scanf("%d", &a[i].anno);
        scanf("%d", &a[i].stipendio);
    }

    scanf("%d", &p);

    aumento(a, 2, p);

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (a[i].stipendio > 1200) {
            printf("%d %d", a[i].codice, a[i].stipendio);
        }
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

your code prints the expected output.

Comment: `a[i].stipendio * ((double)n / 100)` Hu?! Doing `(a[i].stipendio * n) / 100` would just do. Note that the result is saved to an `int`.

Comment: @kamil thank you so much, I always forget about using cast ^^' And yeah, everyone is telling me, I will work on the indentation

Comment: @alk you're right, I fixed the first `a[i].stipendio*(n/100)` and now it works both ways, thanks